# I've bricked my HTC Thunderbolt with Cyan... help?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-thunderbolt, unbricking

Well, this is totally my fault.  I had a little extra to drink last night and on a whim decided to upgrade the Cyan rom on my HTC Thunderbolt.  There appeared a later version in my Rom Manager so I clicked the buttons, gave permissions and off it went... next thing I know, the phone does not get thru the white HTC screen.

Help?  Can anyone provide a simple step-by-step?

Thank you kindly!

Comment: I would try flashing a RUU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to get into the recovery boot menu? (On my phone, it is accessed by holding down the vol down button when turning on the phone). If so, there may be something that can help you. I have had this happen to me, and what I had to do was to try re-installing the ROM from the zip file, using the process described [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/HTC_Thunderbolt%3a_Full_Update_Guide) (scroll down to Flashing CyanogenMod - method via recovery). On that page, it also states "As of right now CyanogenMod is not officially available for the HTC Thunderbolt". I did a bit of digging, and found that the only available CyanogenMod roms for the Thunderbolt are unofficial. At this juncture, I would suggest flashing a different ROM, or an earlier version of Cyanogenmod, if you still have the ZIP file you used before the update.